# Duda con bucle for para ejecutar variables

Tags: python

Hola quiero que este bucle recorra y ejecute cada variable
¿como podria hacer?

```
foto_1 = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\1.jpg"
foto_2 = r"‪C:\Users\user\Desktop\2.jpg"
foto_3 = r"‪C:\Users\user\Desktop\3.jpg"

#subir_fotos("Subir archivo", foto_1)

for i in range(1, 4):
    subir_fotos("Subir archivo", foto_1)
```

Comment: No has definido `lista`. ¿Tal vez `lista=[foto_1, foto_2, foto_3]`. En ese caso, sería `subir_fotos("Subir archivo", i)`

Comment: Disculpa, lo queria hacer sin una lista

Comment: CandidMoe. Aunque prefiero dejarlo como me lo mostraste mejor. Muchisimas gracias.